# React Routers are correct but does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React App with below entery:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Start from './Portal/Membership/Anonymous/Start';
import Register from './Portal/Membership/Anonymous/Register';
import NoMatch from './Portal/Membership/Anonymous/NoMatch';


const App = () => (
    <div className="App" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Start} />
                    <Route exact path="/Register" Component={Register} />
                    <Route component={NoMatch} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

Only path `/` works but if I open `/Start` page will render empty nothing at all even `NoMatch`. If I navigate to incorrect url, `NoMatch` will render.

If I change default component to Register, Register component will render in `/` location

Answer (score 1):

I searched all of web and read all React Router documentation and did not find anything until I accidentally copy and paste one line of routers and find that there are difference between `Component` and `component`!!

I wonder why react did not recognize `Component` attribute (with capital `c`) and did not throw an exception when none of `component`, `render` and `children` defined!

Remember if you write something like `<SomeComponent someBooleanAttribute="true" />` React will warn you with message `although true works here but you must write someBooleanAttribute={true} because someBooleanAttribute="false" will be recognized as true` but NO any warning or error will be shown to developer for this more important problem!

Answer (score 0):

### Bug:

You currently only have routes `/` & `/Register` defined.

### Fix:

You need to declare a route, `/Start`:

```
<Route path="/Start" component={Start} />
```

### Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Start} />
  <Route path="/Start" component={Start} />
  <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
  <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I just added this question and answer to pay attention to case sensitivity of attribute names.

Comment: Ok I see! Were you able to fix the problem?